How do you derive stock price from the Black-Scholes formula?
I am using this formula
$$
\operatorname{C}\left(x\right) =
\operatorname{N}\left(\operatorname{d}_{1}\left(x\right)
\right)S{\rm e}^{-x} - \operatorname{N}\left(\operatorname{d}_{2}\left(x\right)
\right)K{\rm e}^{-x}
$$
$$
\mbox{where}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\operatorname{d}_{1}\left(x\right) & = & {\displaystyle \frac{\ln\left(S/K\right) + \sigma^{2}x/2}
{\sigma \sqrt{x}}}
\\[2mm] \operatorname{d}_2(x) & = & {\displaystyle\frac{\ln\left(S/K\right) - \sigma^{2}x/2}{\sigma \sqrt{x}}}
\end{array}\right.
$$
and $\operatorname{N}$ is just a cumulative normal distribution function defined as
$$
\operatorname{N}\left(x\right) =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_{-\infty}^{x}{\rm e}^{-t^{2}/2}\,{\rm d}t
$$
This is the Black-Scholes formula with dividend yield and interest free rate being zero.
My question is, purely mathematically, how does one solve this equation for S?
I'm not that good at math: I tried expressing N as the error function but I failed at inversing it. The inverse seems to be expressed just as infinite series. Could it be that S can also be solved for as infinite series?
P.S.
I need to solve this to determine conditions at which the option price becomes some particular number. For example, if the current price of an option according to the model is X, I'd like to know what time before expiration and stock price need to be for the option price to be 2X. Ideally, given the volatility and target option price X, I want to plot a function
$$
S(t)
$$
which gives the stock price at time before expiration t, which corresponds to the given volatility and target option price
P.P.S.
I gave up on inverting the formula and decided just to code a program calculating the result using the Newton method. But to apply this method I need to know the derivative of C with respect to S. I tried differentiating it myself but what I got does not seem to be right. I also tried Wolfram alpha but it also failed. So, how do I get the derivative?
$$
\frac{dC}{dS} = ?
$$

The stock price is known... it's observable in the market.  Aa a general matter, numerical methods would be required to invert the expression

@lulu thanks. What I need is to know the stock price based on given option price, volatility, etc. How do I approach inverting the expression?

Again, I'd just do it numerically.  Newton's method is fine.  Of course, it depends how you have implemented the functions.  If you have pre-computed the normal, so that evaluation is essentially a look up, then you may be able to read the inverse off easily.  Or if you are using polynomial approximations, Newton's method is very fast.
